# Firebase.auth & Nest API

Tags: javascript, firebase, nest-api

I'm trying to connect my HMTL5 app in Visual Studio 2015 with my Nest.

Error: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Firebase.auth failed: First argument must be a valid credential (a string).

```
function getNestdata() {
    var accessToken = $.cookie('https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code');
    var ref = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com');
    ref.auth(accessToken);
    console.log("accessToken OK")
    ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `$.cookie("...")`? That may not end up being a string.

Comment: the $.cookie has the Access Token URL from the Nest developers account.

Comment: But does it return a string? What do you see if you `console.log($.cooke(...));`?

Comment: the exact $.cookie('https://xxxx.....') gives: undefined